# How to solve “Failed to instantiate WebApplicationInitializer class”

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I found a good example for generating odata from MySQL at this [GitHub repository](https://github.com/jpenninkhof/odata-boilerplate)

I can run the project by using the command `mvn spring-boot:run -P jar` inside the eclipse. The only part that I changed in comparison to the original code is my connection details to my local MySQL inside the `application.properties` file:

```
# WEB SERVER 
server.port=9090

# MYSQL DATA SOURCE
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/olingo
spring.datasource.username = admin
spring.datasource.password = 123456
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle = true
spring.datasource.validationQuery = SELECT 1

# HANA (CLOUD) DB
#spring.datasource.jndi-name = java:comp/env/jdbc/DefaultDB
#spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
#spring.datasource.testWhileIdle = true
#spring.datasource.validationQuery = SELECT 1

# HSQL DB
#spring.datasource.platform=hsqldb

# JPA / HIBERNATE
spring.jpa.show-sql = false
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy = org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy

# AZURE 
#logging.path = D://home//LogFiles
```

And here is the `pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.penninkhof</groupId>
    <artifactId>odata</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>
    <packaging>${packaging.type}</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>
        <cxf.version>3.1.5</cxf.version>
        <olingo.version>2.0.6</olingo.version>
    </properties>

    <profiles>

        <!-- HANA Cloud Platform -->
        <profile>
            <id>hcp</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <packaging.type>war</packaging.type>
                <tomcat.version>7.0.59</tomcat.version>
            </properties>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
                    <!-- Some exclusions are necessary to make Spring Boot run on HCP. -->
                    <exclusions>
                        <exclusion>
                            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                        </exclusion>
                        <exclusion>
                            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
                            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-el</artifactId>
                        </exclusion>
                        <exclusion>
                            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                        </exclusion>
                    </exclusions>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
                    <!-- Without this exclusions, the HCP runtime will not be so happy -->
                    <exclusions>
                        <exclusion>
                            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                        </exclusion>
                    </exclusions>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.olingo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>olingo-odata2-jpa-processor-api</artifactId>
                    <version>${olingo.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.olingo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>olingo-odata2-jpa-processor-core</artifactId>
                    <version>${olingo.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.1</version>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>

        <!-- Self-contained JAR -->
        <profile>
            <id>jar</id>
            <properties>
                <packaging.type>jar</packaging.type>
            </properties>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.olingo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>olingo-odata2-jpa-processor-api</artifactId>
                    <version>${olingo.version}</version>
                    <exclusions>
                        <exclusion>
                            <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
                            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
                        </exclusion>
                    </exclusions>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.olingo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>olingo-odata2-jpa-processor-core</artifactId>
                    <version>${olingo.version}</version>
                    <exclusions>
                        <exclusion>
                            <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
                            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
                        </exclusion>
                    </exclusions>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>copy-resources</id>
                                <phase>validate</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/classes/static</outputDirectory>
                                    <resources>
                                        <resource>
                                            <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
                                            <filtering>true</filtering>
                                        </resource>
                                    </resources>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>

    </profiles>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.olingo</groupId>
            <artifactId>olingo-odata2-api</artifactId>
            <version>${olingo.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.olingo</groupId>
            <artifactId>olingo-odata2-core</artifactId>
            <version>${olingo.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.olingo</groupId>
            <artifactId>olingo-odata2-api-annotation</artifactId>
            <version>${olingo.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <name>Spring Releases</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

When I try to run the project as `Run on a Server` while I am using Tomcat 9 It will show the following error:

> SEVERE: Error during ServletContainerInitializer processing
>   javax.servlet.ServletException: Failed to instantiate
>   WebApplicationInitializer class   at
>   org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:158)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5140)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)  at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
>     at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:841)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)  at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
>     at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:421)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>     at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:633)    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:343)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:474) Caused
>   by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory   at
>   com.penninkhof.odata.Application.(Application.java:18)    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:155)
>     ... 29 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.slf4j.LoggerFactory   at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1365)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1188)
>     ... 35 more

I can build the project with `mvn clean install` but when I deploy the `war` file inside the Tomcat it cannot run the app. It seems the same issue is the source of the problem!

Any help for solving this issue is appreciated.

Comment: General "how-to" : you can solve many exceptions by looking at their cause (e.g. `Caused by` in your stack trace). Here, you will solve your `ServletException` by solving a `ClassNotFoundException` about SLF4J, which is a pretty actionnable error message.

Comment: Sorry I was new to maven. I will check it.

Comment: Not an issue at all, just a trick, that will help you solve your issues faster, and (or) post a more accurate question and title here on SO if you can't :-) .

Comment: Dear @GPI I added pom.xml. If you check the file the `slf4j-api` is included in the `hcp` profile. It seems the error is somewhere else. if I run the app with `mvn spring-boot:run -P hcp` then I see the following error: `Unable to start ServletW
ebServerApplicationContext due to missing ServletWebServerFactory bean.` .

Comment: If I remove the `<scope>provided</scope>` then application will be compiled but cannot be run as normal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the `pom.xml` and removed the profiles, then I could build the project with `mvn clean install` which will result a `war` file that I can deploy in Tomcat.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.penninkhof</groupId>
    <artifactId>odata</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>
        <cxf.version>3.1.5</cxf.version>
        <olingo.version>2.0.6</olingo.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.olingo</groupId>
            <artifactId>olingo-odata2-jpa-processor-core</artifactId>
            <version>${olingo.version}</version>
        </dependency>       
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.olingo</groupId>
            <artifactId>olingo-odata2-jpa-processor-api</artifactId>
            <version>${olingo.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.olingo</groupId>
            <artifactId>olingo-odata2-api</artifactId>
            <version>${olingo.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.olingo</groupId>
            <artifactId>olingo-odata2-core</artifactId>
            <version>${olingo.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.olingo</groupId>
            <artifactId>olingo-odata2-api-annotation</artifactId>
            <version>${olingo.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-resources</id>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/classes/static</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
                                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <name>Spring Releases</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

**However when I deploy it in the Tomcat it can access the database for some hours and after some hours it cannot anymore fetch data from MySQL!**

When we want to run the app inside the Eclipse with `Run on Server` option, it needs to access the app after a success run like this `http://localhost:9090/<artifactName>/` i.e. `http://localhost:9090/odata/` in this case!

Answer (score 1):

For someone still getting this type of error, it may be because of unavailability of NoArgs Constructor in your main SpringBootApplication. Because of this tomcat is not able to initialise the Servlet. Add a NoArgs constructor in your main class in case you have missed it. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think you didn't let spring know about some bean class.
Look at your xml or configuration file for `LoggerFactory`
In the exception stack above,
it says `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` occured.
Spring can't find class files even if you have them in your java src package.
If my answer doesn't solve your problem,
you need to show your xml or source code to make sure what the problem is.

Comment: I will check it and let you know. All files are as original in GitHub repository. I only changed one place that I already mentioned.

Comment: I added the pom.xml. if I run the app with `mvn spring-boot:run -P hcp` then I see the following error: `Unable to start ServletW ebServerApplicationContext due to missing ServletWebServerFactory bean`.